# Rendering columns dynamically

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I receive JSON(that has products/categories related information) from a Rest API call, on my ReactJS page. I render this information on ag-grid.

Categories are showed horizontally and against each category, products are shown in the columns.

```
---------|-----  |----------|------------
         Product1| Product2 | Product3
---------|-------------------------------
Category1|abc1   | abc2     | abc3
-----------------------------------------
Category2|xyz1   | xyz2     | xyz3
-----------------------------------------
```

The JSON can have any number of categories/products.
I need to able to render the rows/columns dynamically based on this info.
Not sure how to go about this?

Products could be maximum five in number.
Shall I define header definitions of these five products in my reactJS page and then dynamically set the hidden property to true or false, depending upon which product is present in JSON?

```
[{
    headerName: "Product1",
    resizable: true,
    wrapText: true,
    cellStyle: {
        'white-space': 'normal'
    },
    autoHeight: true,
    hide: true
},
{
    headerName: "Product2",
    resizable: true,
    wrapText: true,
    cellStyle: {
        'white-space': 'normal'
    },
    autoHeight: true,
    hide: false
}]
```

---

JSON:
Example1:

```
"raw_message":
[
{
"category": "category1"
[
{
    "product": "Product1"
},
{
    "product": "Product2"
},
]

}

]
```

---

Example2:

```
"raw_message":
[
{
"category": "category1"
[
{
    "product": "Product1"
},
{
    "product": "Product2"
},
{
    "product": "Product3"
},
]

}

]
```

Comment: Can you share your json format for products and cargories related info.

Comment: Hi Mahi, I've added json. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the json format is correct and this is the data you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I managed to resolve the issue by using ag-grid's onRowDataChanged eventhandler and columnAPi's SetColumnVisible property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).